# Accessing radio button value outside the function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need the value of the radio button outside the function.

In the following code, the variable value returns a new value every time the radio button is pressed, however, the date value does not change.

```
    var date_value=2;        
    var $radios = $('input[name=daterange]').change(function () {
    var value = $radios.filter(':checked').val();
    console.log('value'+value);
    date_value = value;
    });
    console.log('date value'+date_value);
```

HTML

```
       <div id="dates" name="daterange">

      <p>
        <input type="radio" id="d1" name="daterange" value='2'/> 
        <label for="d1">24 hours</label>
        <br> 
        <input type="radio" id="d3" name="daterange" value='7'/> 
        <label for="d3">7 days</label>
        <br> 
        <input type="radio" id="d4" name="daterange" value='30'/> 
        <label for="d4">1 month</label>
</div>
```

Comment: At the moment your code executes "declare variable" -> "add function to listener" -> "log variable". By the time you change the value in the listener function the outside log has already executed. What is it that you want to do precisely?

Comment: I want to use the value from the radio button to select a set of files whose data should be displayed in a plot. When a radio button is selected, the x-axis of the plot should change accordingly.